# Пробелы в input mask

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как добавить в регулярное выражение пробел?
Что имею:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="passport_title" name="passport_title" value="" placeholder="" required="">
```

К этому полю подключена маска:

```js
<script>
$(function() {
  //задание заполнителя с помощью параметра placeholder
  $("#passport_title").mask("999-999 *************************************************************************");
});
</script>
```

Код скрипта с регуляркой:

```js
$.mask = {
        definitions: {
            "9": "[0-9]",
            a: "[A-Za-z]",
            я: "[А-Яа-я]",
            "*": "[^a-zA-Z0-9_&nbsp;]"
        },
        autoclear: !0,
        dataName: "rawMaskFn",
        placeholder: "_"
```

Answer (score 1):

\s - это символ пробела, его и вводи в регулярку

Comment: А как правильно ввести его? "9": "[0-9]",
            a: "[A-Za-z]",
            я: "[А-Яа-я]",
            "*": "[A-Za-z0-9\s]"

Comment: попробуй простую строку любую с пробелом. в перле символ пробела вводится двумя символами \s - косая черта и буква s